# caffe Layer type Silence already registered

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I'm new to Caffe and I have a problem running the "Python Layer" example at

- ./example/pycaffe/linreg.prototxt
- ./example/pycaffe/layers/pyloss.py

I prepared temporary "solver.prototxt" as follows:

```
  train_net: "examples/pycaffe/linreg.prototxt"
  base_lr: 0.001
  lr_policy: "step"
  gamma: 0.1
  stepsize: 50000
  display: 20
  momentum: 0.9
  weight_decay: 0.0005
  snapshot: 0
  snapshot_prefix: "linreg"
  iter_size: 2
```

and executed

- ./build/tools/caffe train --solver ./examples/pycaffe/solver.prototxt

But I got the error message as follows:

```
I0611 12:00:12.242858 44085 net.cpp:165] Memory required for data: 1280
I0611 12:00:12.242869 44085 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer loss
F0611 12:00:12.415180 44085 layer_factory.hpp:68] Check failed: registry.count(type) == 0 (1 vs. 0) Layer type Silence already registered.**
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f446d873daa  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446d873ce4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446d8736e6  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446d876687  (unknown)
    @     0x7f43cb656ddb  (unknown)
    @     0x7f43cb623d59  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e74713a  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e747223  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e74bc70  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e746ff4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e74b3bb  (unknown)
    @     0x7f4460ee502b  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446e746ff4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f4460ee562d  (unknown)
    @     0x7f4460ee50c1  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cae82ae  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cab0dae  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb2f729  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb28ae3  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446c9eea3f  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cab9d43  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb32577  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb14c13  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb1854d  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb18682  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb18a2c  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb2f016  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb2f729  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb28ae3  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446c9eea3f  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cab9d43  (unknown)
    @     0x7f446cb32577  (unknown)
```

I'm sorry if this questions are too obvious, I just wasn't able to find a good guide to understand and asking for help here.

P.S.

- Caffe is compiled with option "WITH_PYTHON_LAYER=1"
- $PYTHONPATH is properly set
- Using Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Comment: Did you do `make test && make runtest`? Silence layer initially had a bug https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3151